How does the Functionality know whether a sender/receiver is malicious?
I am new to the field of MPC and I'm trying to learn VOLE. I can understand the maths in functionality and protocols but can't get a sense of the security implications behind them.
For instance, I was reading a paper by Rindal et al. (2021) and came across this functionality. How does the protocol know whether a sender/receiver is malicious, and what will it do if both are malicious/not malicious?

Parameters: There are two parties, a Sender and a Receiver. Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. Let $m$ denote the size of the output vectors.
Functionality: Upon receiving $(\text{sender}, \text{sid})$ from the Sender and $(\text{receiver}, \text{sid})$ from the Receiver.

If the Receiver is malicious, wait for them to send $\vec{C}, \vec{A} \in \mathbb{F}^m$. Sample $\Delta \leftarrow \mathbb{F}$ and compute $\vec{B} := \vec{C} - \vec{A}\Delta$. Otherwise,
If the Sender is malicious, wait for them to send $\vec{B} \in \mathbb{F}^m$, $\Delta \in \mathbb{F}$. Sample $\vec{A} \leftarrow \mathbb{F}^m$ and compute $\vec{C} := \vec{B} + \vec{A}\Delta$. Otherwise,
Sample $\vec{A}, \vec{B} \leftarrow \mathbb{F}^m$, $\Delta \leftarrow \mathbb{F}$ and compute $\vec{C} := \vec{B} + \vec{A}\Delta$.

The functionality sends $\Delta, \vec{B}$ to the Sender and $\vec{C} := \vec{A}\Delta + \vec{B}$, $\vec{A}$ to the Receiver.

Fig. 2: Ideal functionality $\mathcal{F}_{\text{vole}}$ of random reversed Vector-OLE (vole).

The short answer is that the protocol doesn't know who is corrupt. The ideal functionality is allowed to know, though, as in this example. So if the protocol is secure, it means "the adversary can't do more in the protocol than it could do in this ideal world [which gives them some more power than it gives an honest party]."

@Mikero My question is, how can the Ideal Functionality know who is corrupt, and why bother to interact with malicious adversary anyway?

In the real world a corrupt party interacts with an honest party, and causes the honest party to produce some output. How is the adversary going to cause the honest party to produce output also in the ideal world unless the functionality talks to the corrupt party? As for how the functionality knows who is corrupt -- that is just part of the model.

@Mikero According to your comment, can I understand it this way: in the real world, adversary $\mathcal{A}$ can interact with the honest parties and influence their output, whereas in the ideal world, adversary $\mathcal{A'}$ must go through the functionality to affect the honest party's output,so the functionality needs to know who is corrupted?
